# How to update Eclipse GWT Plugin 2.6.0 to higher version

Tags: eclipse, gwt

There seems to be an annoying bug with GWT 2.6.0. Since The current version in the repository for Eclipse is 2.6.0 I was wondering how I could update to 2.6.1 or 2.7.0 myself.

Is there a way to do that?

The error I am dealing with:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromClassPath(Lcom/google/gwt/core/ext/TreeLogger;Ljava/lang/String;Z)Lcom/google/gwt/dev/cfg/ModuleDef;
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.designtime.HostedModeSupportImpl.loadModule(HostedModeSupportImpl.java:85)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.designtime.HostedModeSupportImpl.createModuleSpaceHost(HostedModeSupportImpl.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    ..
```

which gets thrown as I open a file with the GWT Designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download and unzip the SDK manually, then tell Eclipse where to find it: https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/using_sdks#adding-sdks

…but GWT Designer is deprecated and won't work with newer versions of GWT. 2.6.1 is the last that works.

Comment: Deprecated? What would I use instead? Is there an alternative?

Comment: See http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html#Release_Notes_2_7_0_RC1 It's open-source so you can contribute and keep it alive if you really need it: https://github.com/gwt-plugins/gwt-designer Most people apparently just don't use it, according to a fall-2014 study: https://vaadin.com/gwt/report-2015

Comment: Interesting! May I ask you one more little question? Do you think GWT is too much overhead for a simple Web-Interface that is supposed to allow accessing a database?

Comment: No; unless if you're a frontend developer who thinks Java and/or a compiler is too much overhead ;-) (sorry, stackoverflow requires 15 characters minimum)

Comment: :D Alright, thank you. Then I guess I'll stick to GWT. I have to say that I barely use the "Designer" in Android Studio too so I guess Designers are just not meant to be used. :D